# BindingNavigator wont navigate to new record

Tags: bindingnavigator

I'm scratching my head over this one...

Using VB2010, I have a BindingNavigator tied to a dataset. Let's suppose there are only three records in the dataset.

I press the ADD NEW button on the BindingNavigator, and the BN now displays an additional record ("record 3 of 4"). But I cannot get the BN to navigate to record 4! The dataset indicates another record has been added (via dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count). But I can't get there to input new data.

I know how to get the data from the dataset back to the database. Most of the examples I have seen show how to do that. But I havn't found an answer to my problem.

I have a feeling it is something very simple that I am overlooking. Anyone out there in code land have an idea??

Here's the code I use to set up the BN:

```
Sub SetDataBinding()
    Try
        bsCustomers.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)   'ds is my dataset
        txtCustomerName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "CustomerName"))
        txtAddress1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "Address1"))
        txtAddress2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "Address2"))
        txtAddress3.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "Address3"))
        txtCity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "City"))
        txtState.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "State"))
        txtZip.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "Zip"))
        txtHomePhone.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "HomePhone"))
        txtCellPhone.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "CellPhone"))
        txtNotes.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCustomers, "Notes"))
        chkActive.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("checked", bsCustomers, "Active"))
        BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bsCustomers

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some code to help figure it out.

Comment: There is not a lot of code on my form, but here's the section that ties the BN to the data:

Comment: Well, the website says my code it too long to post as a comment. Wonder how to get around that??

Comment: Edit it into your question. You should always do that. Update the original question as things change or need clarification. People should be able to provide accurate answers without having to read through comments.

Comment: Well, how the heck can anyone follow that code? Why can't I post code here??? Dang!

Comment: Don't post it in the comments, edit your original question please.